# drupal6 hook_order($op, &$arg1, $arg2) the third argument is alway coming empty

Tags: drupal-6

I need help. I have a site in Drupal 6 with ubercart. I need to send some user information to third party api when user purchase product do payment and comeback to confirmation page.

When user comeback to confirmation page on that time I need hook to send user info to third api only one time. I am using `hook_order($op, &$arg1, $arg2)` but in which `$op` is always coming load or save and the last `$arg2` is always coming empty and its executing number of times. I want this hook should be run only one time.

Answer (score 0):

A reliable way to accomplish this is to add a predicate on the Conditional Actions page, for the trigger "Customer completes checkout".  You can set up conditions, but the key part is adding an action which executes custom PHP code.

I would call a function defined in a custom module.  From there, you can perform the API routines.